# VB.NET Getting All Items in ListBox and Pass to a Parameter

Tags: vb.net, listbox, parameter-passing

Hi I'm stuck with my loop passing all items in my listbox to a crystal report parameter.

```
    For i = 0 To ListBoxBillAccount.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBoxBillAccount.Items(i).selected Then
            crParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = ListBoxBillAccount.SelectedItems()
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        End If
    Next
```

I'm getting an error: "Public member 'selected' on type 'DataRowView' not found."

Edit: Here's my full code:

```
   Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = crReportDoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions("UserAcct")
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

    For i = 0 To ListBoxBillAccount.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBoxBillAccount.Items(i).selected Then
            crParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = ListBoxBillAccount.SelectedItems()
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        End If
    Next

    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
    frmGenerateConsolidatedBill.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDoc
    frmGenerateConsolidatedBill.Refresh()
    frmGenerateConsolidatedBill.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
For Each obj In ListBoxBillAccount.SelectedItems()
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = obj
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
Next
```

Comment: I tried inserting your code but I encountered an error: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: @Sishan: Is `crParameterValues` another `ListBox` whoch already contains that object?